# asyncio.wait does not stop a co-routine with websocket call when another co-routine has exception

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I have two co-routines. One handles connection to a websocket server. Another one does something arbitrary. I want to terminate the program when an exception happens. However, the co-routine that handles the connection to websocket server, keeps running.
Please see this sample (No need for any websocket server, simply run this code and it tries to reconnect to a server):

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def task1():
    """ A dummy co-routine
    After five iterations. raise an exception"""
    
    i = 1
    while True:
        print(f"In task 1 iteration {i}")
        if i == 5:
            raise Exception("Terminate task 1")
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def task2():
    """ Connect to websocket server"""
    i = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Attempt {i} to connect to server")
        try:
            await websockets.connect("ws://localhost:9090")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            break

        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    tasks = [task1(), task2()]

    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
    for task in finished:
        try:
            await task
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception detected:", repr(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Start")
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("End")
```

The output is:

```
Start
In task 1 iteration 1
Attempt 1 to connect to server
In task 1 iteration 2
In task 1 iteration 3
Multiple exceptions: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9090), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('::1', 9090, 0, 0)
In task 1 iteration 4
Attempt 2 to connect to server
In task 1 iteration 5
Exception detected: Exception('Terminate task 1')

Attempt 3 to connect to server
Multiple exceptions: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9090), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('::1', 9090, 0, 0)
Attempt 4 to connect to server
Multiple exceptions: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9090), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('::1', 9090, 0, 0)
Attempt 5 to connect to server
```

What is wrong here?
I am using python 3.7.7 . The websokets version is 8.1 .

**Update**

I installed python 3.8.2 and the result is different. The application terminates as soon as exception occurs. Here is the output:

```
Start
Attempt 1 to connect to server
In task 1 iteration 1
In task 1 iteration 2
In task 1 iteration 3
[WinError 1225] The remote computer refused the network connection
In task 1 iteration 4
Attempt 2 to connect to server
In task 1 iteration 5
Exception detected: Exception('Terminate task 1')
End
```

Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-raise the CancelledError in `task2()`. Otherwise, the task is not cancelled. 
   When `main()` exit, `asyncio.run` will try to cancel all tasks running and wait until they are done. The `except Exception` statement catches the CancelledError raised and results in forever waitings in `asyncio.run`.

The following are optional to the question, though they are good practice.

2. Wrap the coroutine object using `asyncio.create_task()` or `asyncio.ensure_future()` to treat it as a future-like object (the task will be scheduled in the event loop).
3. Iterate over the unfinished tasks and cancel them.
4. Preferably, `await` on the cancelled tasks to see any other errors.

```py
async def task2():
    """ Connect to websocket server"""
    i = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Attempt {i} to connect to server")
        try:
            await websockets.connect("ws://localhost:9090")
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(task1()),
        asyncio.create_task(task2()),
    ]

    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
    for task in finished:
        try:
            await task
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception detected:", repr(e))

    for task in unfinished:
        task.cancel()

    for task in unfinished:
        try:
            await task.result()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception detected:", repr(e))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I was expecting `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION` terminates every co-routine no matter what. Actually, it is the case in python 3.8. I just installed python 3.8 and ran the sample code as is. It terminates. 
Is this a bug in python 3.7 or is it improved in 3.8?